# Excel vba: Create a macro to connect a slicer to multiple pivot tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will change the data source for three pivot tables.  Then, a single slicer that is already on the sheet will be connected to all three pivot tables.  The pivot tables all will take their data from the same place.

When I try this, I get an error at the step to connect the slicer to pivot tables 2 and 3.  If I run the macro with only the steps to change the data source for each pivot table, I noticed that the slicer only has one option in the "report connections" box instead of 3.

Here is what I have:

```
Sheets("Sales").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Table3", Version _
:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Table3", Version _
:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Table3", Version _
:=xlPivotTableVersion15)


ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Year").PivotTables.AddPivotTable ( _
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"))
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Year").PivotTables.AddPivotTable ( _
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2"))
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Year").PivotTables.AddPivotTable ( _
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3"))
```

Comment: try reading about `Slicers` and `SlicerCache` here http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/slicers03.asp. How to do it manually http://myexcelonline.com/blog/connect-slicers-to-multiple-excel-pivot-tables/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was the last parenthesis which was causing the error.
So you should replace this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Year").PivotTables.AddPivotTable ( _
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2"))
```

with this:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Year").PivotTables.AddPivotTable _
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
```

Also you could write your code in this way:

```
Dim WB as Workbook
Dim WS as Worksheet

Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Sheets("Sales")

WB.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Year").PivotTables.AddPivotTable _ 
WS.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
```